# Prove $A\cap (B-C) = (A\cap B) - (A\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does Prove $A\cap (B-C) = (A\cap B) - (A\cap C)$?

So I've drawn a bunch of diagrams, tried a few numerical examples and it appears like it is a true statement. So I've attempted to prove it but I'm not sure if I could do all these operations.

Pf:

LHS:  $$A\cap(B-C) = A\cap (B-(B\cap C)) = [unsure\ line](A\cap B) - A\cap(B\cap C) = (A\cap B) - (A\cap B\cap C)$$

RHS:  $$(A\cap B) - (A\cap C) = (A\cap B)- ((A\cap B) \cap (A\cap C)) = [unsure\ line](A\cap B) - (A\cap B\cap C)$$

and RHS = LHS.

Done

Comment: If you can do the first "unsure line", distributing $\cap$ over $-$, why not just do it to start with?  Then you'd get $A\cap(B-C)=(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$ right away.

Comment: You have three options here: draw some Venn diagrams, consider the 8 possibilities of $x \in $ or $x \notin $ $A$, $B$ or $C$, or use characteristic functions.

Comment: @Steven I was not sure if I was allowed to distribute $ A\cap (B-(B\cap C)) = (A\cap B) - A\cap(B\cap C) $ Since I'm really dealing with algebraic quantities I was unsure if it was allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in A\cap (B-C)$, i.e., $x\in A$ and $x\in B-C$, i.e, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ but $x\notin B-C$, i.e. $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\notin A\cap C$, i.e., $x\in (A\cap B)- (A\cap C)$. So, $A\cap (B-C)\subseteq (A\cap B)- (A\cap C)$.

Conversely, let us assume that $x\in (A\cap B)- (A\cap C)$, i.e., $x\in A\cap B$ but $x\notin A\cap C$, i.e., $x\in A$, $x\in B$ but $x\notin C$, i.e., $x\in A$ and $x\in B-C$, i.e., $x\in A\cap (B-C)$. So, $ (A\cap B)- (A\cap C) \subseteq A\cap (B-C)$.

Note: The most basic idea to show equality of two sets $A$ and $B$, that is, $A= B$, is to show that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 3):

$(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)=(A\cap B)\cap(\overline{A\cap C})\stackrel{\text{DM}}=(A\cap B)\cap (\overline{A}\cup \overline{C})$

$\stackrel{\text{Distr.}}=((A\cap B)\cap \overline A)\cup((A\cap B)\cap \overline C)=\varnothing\cup ((A\cap B)\cap \overline C)$

$=(A\cap B)\cap \overline C=A\cap(B\cap\overline{C})=A\cap(B-C)$.

DM-DeMorgan, Distr-distributive property.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in A\cap(B- C)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ and $c\not\in C$. therefore $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\not\in A\cap C$, therefore $x\in (A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$.

If $x\in (A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$ then $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\not\in (A\cap C)$. Because $x\in (A\cap B)$ we have $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. From $x\in A$ and $x\not \in (A\cap C)$ we have $x\not\in C$. So we have $x\in B,x\not \in C$. From here $x \in (B-C)$. Combining this with $x\in A$ we have $x\in A\cap (B-C)$