# Understanding the Set Theory Relationship $A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B)-(A \cap C)$

Tags: set-theory

I am very new to set theory and have began with *Naive Set Theory* by Paul Halmos. In chapter 5 (pg. 18) he presents some ‘exercises’ for the reader on complementation. The fourth relation presented states the following:
$$
A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B)-(A \cap C)
$$
I have found the mathematical proof of this statement elsewhere and whilst it does make sense, intuitively I can’t seem to understand it.

Using Venn diagrams, the left hand side of the relation is shown as follows, with the complement of B and C shown in yellow and the intersect with A shown in red:
[image]

From the right hand side of the relation, the two intersects are shown in blue and green on the following diagram and the complement of these is outlined in red. What I don’t understand is why we need to use $(A \cap C)$ when taking the complement, when just C would give the same result?

[image]

I just wondered if anyone could explain why? Note, I am not looking for a formal mathematical proof of $A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B)-(A \cap C)$ as this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267384/prove-a-cap-b-c-a-cap-b-a-cap-c) and elsewhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A, B$, and $C$ be subsets of some set $S$. Then for $A - B$ denoting the relative complement of $A$ with respect to $B$, $A - B = A \cap B^c$, where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$. So

$$A \cap (B - C) = A \cap (B \cap C^c) = (A \cap B) \cap C^c = (A \cap B) - C$$

since set intersection is associative.

However, I presume the purpose of this exercise is to show that set intersection distributes over relative complement. From this perspective, "just intersecting with C" would miss the point.